# How to validate mobile number in Regular Expression

Tags: regex, validation

I am trying to validate mobile using regular expression

so for i have tried 
    https://regex101.com/#javascript

My Expresion is `((\d[^0-5]|[6-9])\d{9})|^(\d)\1*$`

i need validate moblie number like below

> 1.it should not start with 0-5
>
> e.g 0600432102
>
> 2.not all the same or in sequence
>
> e.g 1111111111 or 0123456789 or 9876543210
>
> 3.lenght is 10 digit

where i made error.

help me....

thanks ....

Comment: What is wrong with `9876543210`?

Comment: its is revers sequence number

Comment: Note that `[^0-5]` will match `acf#$%^`. I guess you wanted to match the other digits: `[6-9]`.

Comment: @Eirik Birkeland i am trying with regular expression...if you give solution by using javascript  i am happy with that too.....

Comment: @jana can you share your code with us?

Comment: `([6-9]\d{9})` for rule1. The following rules could be easily implemented in other ways rather than regex.

Comment: Please check [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/edx9uj4t/2/) will suffice. I tried to split the conditions so that the code was more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This covers all criteria and tests a few numbers. It does however not specify the reason for a number being invalid - I leave that to you.

```
var numArr = ["1111111111", "0123456789", "9876543210", "8682375827", "83255"];

for (var i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {
    console.log(numArr[i] + " is " + validate(numArr[i]));
}

function validate(num) {
    if ((num.match(/^[6-9]\d{9}$/) && (!num.match(/^([0-9])\1{9}$/))) && (!isIncr(num) && (!isDecr(num)))) {
        return ( "Valid") ;
    } else {
        return ( "Not valid") ;
    }
}

function isIncr(num) {
    for (var i = 1; i < num.length; i++) {
        if (num[i] == parseInt(num[i - 1]) + 1) {
            continue;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function isDecr(num) {
    for (var i = 1; i < num.length; i++) {
        if (num[i] == parseInt(num[i - 1]) - 1) {
            continue;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Updated. JavaScript tricked me at that part (needed parseInt).

Answer (score 1):

```
(([6-9])(?!\2{9})\d{9})
```

will:

1. Check if the number starts with `6-9`. It stores this in match group `2`.
2. Check that the first digit is not followed by exactly `9` (you can set the limits here) repetitions of the same digit.
3. Continues to find if there are 9 more digits after the first digit.

will not:

1. Check whether the numbers are ascending/descending order.
2. Check for patterns such as `6566666666`

Comment: I like the use of \2 in a lookahead, but why capture the entire expression?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following regex:

```
 /^(?!9876543210)(?!([\d])\1{9})[6-9][\d]{9}$/mg
```

Explanation

**(?!9876543210)** Check that the string is different (it's the only sequence possible)

**(?!([\d])\1{9})** Check that this is not the same number repeated

**[6-9][\d]{9}** Check that the number start with 6 to 9, followed by 9 numbers

Comment: Brilliant. This covers it all in a single regex.

Comment: Did you put [ ] on \d for legibility or is there some other reason for it?

Comment: @EirikBirkeland There is no reason, at all ;)

Answer (score 0):

This regex works for repititions and numbers not starting with `0-5`.

```
(?!([0-9])\1{9})(\b[6-9]\d{9})
```

See demo here: https://regex101.com/r/uJ0vD4/9

It doesn't detect ascending and descending numbers. You can achieve that using a loop in your program